# Is it possible to get the value from a method that returns a value, when called inside an actor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

I have an actor defined like this

```
class RandomActor @Inject() (
                             accounts: models.Accounts
                             )extends Actor with ActorLogging{
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case Create(address, username, type, password) => {
      accounts.Service.create(address, username, type, password)
    }
  }
}
```

`Accounts` is a model class with an `object` called `Service` which has the `create` method.
This `create` method returns a `Future[String]`. So when I'm trying to call this create method from an actor, is it possible to return the `Future[String]` from the actor as a message which can be stored into a variable outside an actor?

Comment: Actors don't really "return" things, they just send messages to each other. Are you asking how to send the result of `create` in a message?

Comment: Yes, how can we send that in a message @Tim

Comment: But that message can only be sent to another actor right?

Comment: Have modified the question. Do check. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be two questions here: How to generate a message from a `Future` and how to get a message "out" of the actor system.

The answer to the first question is to use `onComplete` on the `Future`:

```
 accounts.Service.create(address, username, type, password).onComplete{
   case Success(account) =>
     otherActor ! AccountCreated(account)
   case Failure(e) =>
     otherActor ! CreateAccountFailed(address, username, type)
 }
```

This will send the appropriate message when the `Future` completes (either successfully or with an error).

The answer to the second question is to use the `ask` pattern that allows a message to be sent to an actor from outside the actor system and a reply received:

```
(RandomActor ? RequestMessage).mapTo[ReplyType].onComplete {
  case Success(reply) =>
    // process reply
  case Failure(e) =>
    // process error
}
```

Note that the answer will appear asynchronously on a separate thread, so care is needed when processing this sort of reply. See [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#send-messages) for more details on ask.